# I need to drop all rows based on condition but if there are null entries in the column, I want to keep those rows

Tags: python, pandas

The dataframe I'm using has a column for ages, called age. There are entries in the age column that and meaningless, as in it has values over 101 and below 1. The age column also has null entries.

I want to delete the rows for the invalid ages.
Then, I want to fill the null entries with the mean age of what's left.

```
df = df[(df.age <102) & (df.age > 0)]
```

When I do this, it drops not only the meaningless ages but the null entries, too. I thought about filling with the mean first, but I don't want the meaningless ages to be included and misrepresent the mean.

Comment: Umm.. does... `df[df.age.isna() | df.age.between(0, 102)]` do what you're after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in, at least, two ways:

**Method one:**

keep also `nan` values in your mask:

```
df = df[((df.age <102) & (df.age > 0))|(df.age.isnull())]
```

and then fill the `nan` values:

```
df = df.fillna(df.age.mean())
```

**Method two:**

fill the `nan` values by applying `mean` just on masked dataframe:

```
df = df.fillna(df[((df.age <102) & (df.age > 0))]["age"].mean())
```

and then apply the mask:

```
df = df[((df.age <102) & (df.age > 0))]
```